# MySQL Select with regex

Tags: mysql, regex

I don't know how to create regex for my query.

```
SELECT type REGEXP '***' AS parent FROM items;
```

In type column I have values:

```
/123/
/234/111/
/43/
/1/324/
```

etc.

I want to get from above values:

```
123
111
43
324
```

Answer (score 0):

This would involve using a regular expression *replace* on the values in the database. While MySQL offers a [`REGEXP` operator](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/regexp.html), it doesn't natively implement any way to search and replace via regular expressions.

Additionally, MySQL's `REGEXP` operator is very limited. The regular expression provided in [Fede's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24912290/2038227) won't work, because MySQL uses an implementation of regular expressions that's completely different from PCRE (PHP), JavaScript, Python, etc.

It would be a better to retrieve values from a more general query and then use a regex replace server-side to filter them.

Comment: It doesn't. You'll have to read the [documentation for the REGEXP operator](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/regexp.html), because MySQL's flavor of regular expressions is completely different from PHP, Javascript, or Python.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the latest numbers before your slash so you can also use this regex:

```
.*\/(\d+)\/
```

Here you have a working example:

http://regex101.com/r/wA0xF8/2